# How to use google translate for translating a specific part of web page?

Tags: html, google-translate

I want to use google translate for one of my web pages and it worked fine.
but i want to use it for a specific part of my web page for example a textarea.
how can do that?
is it possible or not ?
this is my code ....

```
<h1>My Web Page</h1>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<form method="post">
<textarea placeholder="type something .... "></textarea>
</form>
```

and also javascript code here ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```